# How to take user to a specific landing page using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, routes

I am trying to replace an existing application with a new `angularjs` application. In existing application user comes to a specific landing page from external app through a specific url something like

```
'localhost:8080/APP_NAME/recordPage?recordId=ABC123'.
```

I am trying to implement new app using angularjs. I managed to build app to access

```
'localhost:8080/APP_NAME/#/recordPage?recordId=ABC123'
```

using angular routing mechanism. But is it possible to make url available exactly as it was before with out `'#/'?`.

In spring framework i can define it in controller to return to landing page directly, but is it even possible in angularjs to directly access specific page without going home page or index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by creating a separate servlet to handle direct access using servlet annotations

```
'@WebServlet("/recordPage")'
```

Answer (score 0):

`localhost:8080/APP_NAME` this is your context path and in angularJs '#' differ context path with specific accessing path.
So when ever you want to access another page it simply change the path after #, so it is easy to set state with particular url.
& if you don't want to go through '#' then don't declare your file path in index page and access it from outside.

Comment: How to access it directly from outside? If i declare in routing it always expects something like 'localhost:8080/APP_NAME/#/recordPage?recordId=ABC123'. I get 404 error if i try to access 'localhost:8080/APP_NAME/recordPage?recordId=ABC123'

Comment: yes for that you have to give access from your backend, in spring add .antMatchers("../recordPage.html").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()

Comment: since I am not using spring here, can i achieve similar functionality in angularjs?